# create a loop that will output the age and name of each. in the format "name(has age years)"

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

the question is: to create a loop that will output the name and age of each.

```
example =[
    
    {"name":"Ana","age": 16,"country":'india','hobbies':['futboll']} , 
    {'name' :'Leo ' ,'age' : 20 , ' country ' : ' USA' ,'hobbies ' : ['fishing']},
    {'name':'Mia ' , 'age' : 64 , 'country ' : 'cuba' , ' hobbies ' :['read']},
    {'name':'Ian','age':43,'country':'france','hobbies':[tennis]} 
    ]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far and where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Please [edit] and tag a language. [tag:python]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
example =[
    
    {"name":"Ana","age": 16,"country":'india','hobbies':['futboll']} , 
    {'name' :'Leo' ,'age' : 20 , ' country ' : ' USA' ,'hobbies ' : ['fishing']},
    {'name':'Mia' , 'age' : 64 , 'country ' : 'cuba' , ' hobbies ' :['read']},
    {'name':'Ian','age':43,'country':'france','hobbies':['tennis']} 
]

for ex in example:
    print('{} (has {} yesrs)'.format(ex['name'], ex['age']))
```

Output:

```
Ana (has 16 yesrs)
Leo (has 20 yesrs)
Mia (has 64 yesrs)
Ian (has 43 yesrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in example:
    print(i['name'], i['age'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in example:
    print(i["name"], i["age"])
```

You can use python dictionaries with key-value pairs. It is fundamental to the python programming language. Personal suggestion, more tutorials on it.

Comment: can u recommend any tutorials on this?

Comment: f-strings will give the desired output format: `print(f"{i['name']}(has {i['age']} years)")`

Comment: @IgnacioTaylor you can follow him: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-HLU9Fl5ug